# how to access variables outside of query callback in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm making an app in node.js and I stucked on one place. I run a query and then I want to push these query results in an array and return that array. Problem is that it does not access that array outside of query callback. My code looks like below.

```
var emailsToReturn = [];

    emails.forEach(( email, index ) => {
        var msgId = email.message_id;

        //fetch attachments against this attachment

        var fetchAttachments = `SELECT * FROM email_attachments WHERE message_id='${msgId}'`;
        connection.query(fetchAttachments, (err, attachmentsResult)=>{

            email['attachments'] = attachmentsResult;                
            emailsToReturn.push(email); // this show desired results here.
        });


    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(emailsToReturn, null, 4)); // this shows empty array here outside of query callback.
```

I know this is scope issue and I tried to use `global` too. But that didn't worked either. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happening here is that emailsToReturn is global variable and can be access anywhere. You are updating values of emailsToReturn and then tries to print it.

---

But what really happening is JavaScript is Updating values of emailsToReturn in background and while that process is going on JavaScript execute next instruction which is console.log . So values are still updating in background and you goes to next instruction and print the value of variable which is still the same.
**How to solve?**

You can use async/await (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/)

---

I have use await.Now Javascript will wait for query's result and then update the array and then goes to next instruction.

```
var emailsToReturn = [];
async function functionName(emails,index){
 emails.forEach(( email, index ) => {
    var msgId = email.message_id;

    //fetch attachments against this attachment

    var fetchAttachments = `SELECT * FROM email_attachments WHERE message_id='${msgId}'`;
    let attachmentsResult = await connection.query(fetchAttachments)
    if(attachmentsResult.err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
        email['attachments'] = attachmentsResult;                
        emailsToReturn.push(email); // this show desired results here.
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(emailsToReturn, null, 4));
//req.send(JSON.stringify(emailsToReturn, null, 4));//use to send response
}
 functionName(emails,index)
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` this error is appearing now. I think I have to use `async` keyword somewhere. In case of functions, we can use `async` before `function` keyword. But in `Node.js` I am writing these lines in `app.post('/path', (req, res)=> {}` Where do I use async?

Comment: @Asadullah i have edited the post.Have a look if it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are trying to do would not give you desired results due to asynchronous nature of nodejs. Your console runs before the loop (being asynchronous due to db operation). You can use waterfall method from async library and try something like this, after initializing you "emails":

```
const async = require("async");
var emailsToReturn = [];
async.waterfall([function(cb){
 emails.forEach(( email, index ) => {
        var msgId = email.message_id;

        //fetch attachments against this attachment

        var fetchAttachments = `SELECT * FROM email_attachments WHERE message_id='${msgId}'`;
        connection.query(fetchAttachments, (err, attachmentsResult)=>{

            email['attachments'] = attachmentsResult;                
            emailsToReturn.push(email); // this show desired results here.
            if(index == emails.length - 1){
             cb();  
            }
        });
     });
}],function(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(emailsToReturn, null, 4));
})
```